# Embedded JavaScript (EJS) - Dynamically setting view from route

Tags: node.js, ejs, embedded-javascript

I'm learning nodejs at the moment and my .ejs template files are pretty much standard (header, footer, js-defaults etc) - and the only thing that changes it the content in a HTML div.

I thought I could set a variable in my route and pass it along to the view (like you would a title or another variable), then include it - but it's not working (example below).

In Ruby you can do this with "yield" and I am trying to do the same with EJS.

Thanks for taking the time to read (and please forgive my ignorance in this matter).

**Example Route**

```
app.get('/fish', function(req, res) {

res.render('fish' {
    title:"Fish",
    template:"view/partials/content/fish.ejs"
});
```

});

**Example EJS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<% include views/partials/template/header.ejs %>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Dynamic content here -->
      <% include template %> <!-- tries to load template.ejs %>
    </div>
</body>
<% include views/partials/template/footer.ejs %>
<% include views/partials/template/js-defaults.ejs %>
</html>
```

Comment: use `<%= title %>` instead `<% title %>` to output it to html, as in rails (.erb).

Comment: Thanks @Ravi - meant to put that in my example. It's the dynamic content I am stuck with though - not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: Well, i don't know is this supported yet or not, but check this out, https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/93.

Comment: Thank you again @Ravi - maybe I should use Jade instead then (not a fan personally) - +1 for your help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like this is now supported in EJ](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes)S. It was introduced in [v2.0.1: 2015-01-02](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v201-2015-01-02). The new syntax looks like this

```
 <!-- Dynamic content here -->
      <%- include(template) %>
```

**To get this to work** I had to disable caching in Express by setting:

```
app.set('view cache', false);
```